# Finding grok pattern for file with varying structure

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have a log file where not all the lines are in the same format. How do I find the correct grok pattern for such a file.

```
[15:37:20:030|1] [TdmUtil.c: 1534:fnTDM_LoadLocalFoo] F_LAA       : 1
[15:37:20:032|1] [TdmUtil.c: 1281:fnTDM_GetPreDef]  pdeGetData : MAX_IRAT_NBR_PER_SERVED_CELL_SYS = 256
[15:37:20:091|1] [TdmUtil.c:  293:fnTDM_PrtIndexKey] fnTDM_GetIndexKeyNum Error!!
```

In this way few of the lines are in the format of line1, few in the format of line2 and so on. I could write a grok pattern for each of these lines, but I have no idea how to combine them. Is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: You want to combine all those lines in one event or you want to use grok to parse those lines? It is not clear. Your log lines have a common structure, you can make a grok filter to parse the common part and other groks filters for the parts the are not common.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to use more than one grok filter to parse a single log file.

Comment: You can have as many grok patterns as you need in the same grok filter, just add another `match` line with your pattern, you can also have as many grok filter as you need. What is current logstash config? Update your question with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have put something together for you. but before I share it with you I suggest you to work with online GROK debugger in order to write your GROK pattern (there is 1 inside Kibana if you are working with it under Dev Tools -> GROK debugger).
You should also check out the [available GROK patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).

I see all 3 lines has the same prefix which is `[time|num] [class: line number: function name] log text` I have created a GROK patter for that. if you want to break down the `log text` further you can do so by uncomment the second match over the `text` field and provide the needed grok patter.

NOTE: you can add as many more `match` sections as you want, but beware that it will try to run the match on all of them. try using `if else` statements to navigate through for high complexity- usually it is not needed.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/work/elastic/logstash-6.5.0/config/test.txt"
        start_position => "beginning"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^\[%{TIME}\|"
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
        }
        type => "whatever"
    }
}
filter {
    if [type] == "whatever" {
        grok {
            break_on_match => false
            match => { "message" => "^\[%{TIME:time}\|%{NUMBER:num}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:class}:%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:linenumber:int}:%{DATA:function}\]%{GREEDYDATA:text}$"}
            #match => { "text" => ""}
        }
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
        index => "test"
    }
}
```

The above configuration file will provide you with the following fields in Kibana:

[image]